# Power amplifier schematic details identification

Tags: power, amplifier, multisim

I have that power amplifier schematic.

[image]

1. Why it's written that it's class A? I think that only voltage gain stage is class A and output is class AB or it's not so?
2. Why the collector of Q8 is at ground? What that ground actually do and does the Q8-Q9 stage is a darlington stage or not?
3. How much voltage must be between C-E of Q10 rubber diode to avoid output distortion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Class A simply means that even under maximum signal conditions, the output transistors (here Q12 and Q14) should  **always** have some collector current flowing through them.

So is it simply a matter of biasing (choosing the operating point) of the output stage such that this (Ic > 0) is always true. You can do that by making the quiescent current large and/or limiting the maximum power.

So I could also for example say that this same design is a 40 W **class AB** Audio amplifier (I'm for argument's sake assuming it can do 40 W in class AB) which works in **class A** up to 20 W.

2) The collector of Q8 just needs to be connected to a supply rail. If it was connected to the +22 V rail then Q8 would need to dissipate a lot more power. Since the emitter of Q8 is at about -21.3 V (-22 V + 0.7 V) there is plenty of "headroom" for Q8 to have 0 V (ground) at the collector. So there's nothing special about the connection to ground, it is used as a supply rail.

Yes Q8 and Q9 indeed form a darlington pair. This limits the load on the current output formed by Q1 and Q3. If Q8 was removed the gain in the amplifier would drop significantly.

3) The "zener" made by Q10 sets the **quiescent** current in the output stage. So as mentioned under 1) you can then choose the range in which the amplifier works in class A. In creasing the voltage means a higher quiescent current and also a higher power dissipation!

The overall distortion of this amplifier is not only determined by how much voltage you set across Q10. This amplifier also has **feedback**, not the 510 ohm and 10 kohm resistors connected to the base of Q2. This feedback network (10 kohm + 510 ohm + 220 uF capacitor, ignore the diodes, they are for protection only) sets the **gain** of the amplifier and this also **reduces distortion**.

So the overall distortion is determined by both the feedback and how you set the quiescent current of the output stage.

Comment: The D1, D2 protection normally does nothing as there should be no DC voltage (0 V DC) across the 220 uF cap. If there was 1 V DC across that cap then that would mean there would have to be a DC voltage at the **output of the amplifier** as well. Would you like some DC across your speakers? No, neither would I.

Comment: It can happen that after power on there is some DC across the 220 uF cap and that is OK as long as it is positive (VDC > 0). Since the 220 uF cap is polarized it cannot handle a large **negative** voltage. That's where D1 and D2 come in, they then conduct and limit it to -1.4 V which is OK

Comment: **You choose** what you want as the quiescent current in the output stage and set VR1 accordingly, you measure the voltage across the 0.1 ohm resistors and calate the current. 100 mV across 0.1 ohm is 1 A. There is no right/wrong it is just a trade off you can make between power dissipation and class A operation.

Comment: May be Q10 CE voltage less than 1.4V?

Comment: Is it valid to suppose that if for example I choose 100 mv across 0.1 ohm I will get the class A operation before the ouput collector current achieves 1A and after that it will be the class AB operation?

Comment: There are values indicated for the 0.1 ohm Res.: 112 mV. Vbe of Q11 and Q13 will be 0.7 to 0.8 V so in total Vce of Q10 needs to be between 1.6 and 1.8 V. It is not exactly predictable that's why VR1 is there, set VR1 to highest resistance (so Vce of Q10 is smallest) then measure across 0.1 ohm res. and slowly increase VR1 untill it reaches 112 mV. It will drift over temperature though so be aware. I'd mount Q11, Q12, Q13, Q14 and Q10 all on the same heatsink for best temperature stability.

Comment: How much the initial current for Q7 base using 2x10kOhm can be set?

Comment: If you want that much detail I suggest to build this in a circuit simulator (LTSpice for example) and try it out.

Comment: I'm building that in Multisim and now trying to understand the details that I can't find in any textbook. You are good tutor and can greatly clarify my gaps. Can you answer last question about 2x10kOhms?

Comment: That 2 x 10 kohm does not set the current through Q7! Look at Q6, it takes the base current away from Q7 (and Q5 as well). It does that when the voltage across the 68 resistor gets more than about 0.6 V. The circuit around Q6, Q7 is a **current source**, it supplies a constant current into Q10. The current is 0.6 V / 68 ohms = 9 mA.

Comment: Why if Q8/Q9 is a darlington pair, the Q8 collector can't be simply connected to Q9 collector (not to ground)?

Comment: I think that that is for better performance when the audio signal is very large and the voltage on the collector of Q9 needs to go very low. Suppose we want the voltage at the collector of Q9 to go down to -20 V so Vce of Q9 = 2 V. If the collector of Q8 was connected to the collector of Q9 then Q8 would be very near saturation. We can avoid this by giving Q8 a lot of voltage to "work with" and this is done by connecting it to ground.

Comment: @MaxMil Strictly speaking Q8 is emitter follower. And Q8 collector is connected to ground instead of Q9 collector, because in the emitter follower the non-linear Cbc capacitor (voltage dependent) is not multiplied by the stage gain (no Miller effect occur in EF). Also Q8 help separate the Q9 Cbc capacitance from the Miller compensation capacitor 100pF. Without Q8 transistor Q9 Cbc capacitor is in parallel with Miller compensation capacitor. And because Cbc is a non-linear capacitance (voltage dependent) we have another source of a distortion in the amplifier. And Q8 reduce this effect.

Comment: @G36 What are 100 ohm's resistors used for in bases of Q11/Q13

Comment: @G36 What is the purpose of 47 uF capacitor connected from "+" rail to the mid-point between 2*10 kOhm resistors (between Q5/Q7)? Is it not enough initial current for Q5/Q7 current source that go through 2*10 kOhm without capacitor?

Comment: @G36 What path the current will go through D1/D2 protection diodes to make it opened? Is it will occur due to the inductive part of an amplifier load?

Comment: @G36 Is it true that the capacitor 220 uF which is parallel to D1/D2 allows to make infinite Av gain for DC (steady-state) and used for feedback only when AC input signal is applied?

Comment: 100 ohm Rs: they are there to make enough current flow through Q11 and Q13. Without them there would only be the base current of Q12 and Q14, that's a small current and Q13, Q14 would not work properly. More current is needed, that's what the 100 ohms Rs do.

Comment: 47 uF cap across BE of Q5: is a low pass filter with the 2.2 k resistor. Q5 must supply a DC current for Q1 and Q2, to do that Q5 must have a constant Vbe. The voltage at the right side of the 2.2 k resistor can have some signal on it. The 2.2 k res and 47 uF cap filter this out so Ic of Q5 becomes a DC current.

Comment: For the DC voltage thanks to the 220uF capacitor the amplifier gain (closed loop gain) is equal to one. The 100 ohm's resistors at Q11/Q13 bases are "base stopper resistors they separate the output stage (emitter follower) from the VAS. This helps damps parasitic oscillations. 47uF cap is just here to quiet the GND variations (smoothing cpacitor).

Comment: And D1/D2 are just a protection diodes. The electrolytic capacitors will blow if reverse polarity voltage is larger than -1.6V. So, the D1/D2 protect the cap from blowing up if an output stage failure occurs and the DC negative supply voltage appears at the output.